# RUN FAILED (exit value 127) in netbeans MinGW c++

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, mingw

Hello when trying to run one of my programs the BUild is succesfull.

> "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
>   SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make.exe[1]: Entering directory
>   `/c/Users/ruben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jelly'
>   "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/jelly.exe make.exe[2]: Entering directory`
>   /c/Users/ruben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jelly' mkdir -p
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
>   g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp mkdir -p
>   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/jelly
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -lcurldll make.exe[2]: Leaving
>   directory `/c/Users/ruben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jelly'
>   make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /c/Users/ruben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jelly'
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)

My other programs work just fine so I **assume** it doesn't have anything to do with the Path variable..
But I put the  ouput here anyway

C:\Windows\System32>echo %path:;=&echo.%

> c:\Perl64\site\bin
>
> C:\Perl64\bin
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
>
> C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32
>
> C:\WINDOWS
>
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
>
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64
>
> C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
>
> C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
>
> C:\MinGW\bin
>
> C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin

I tought it might have been the makefile so I recreated the project (needless to say it didn't work)

I also tried to compile with -static-libstdc++ to avoid the wrong dll being linked or somehing (cause I saw it  on another stackoverflow post)

When I change the console type to standard output this retarted visual studio JIT debugger pops up.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Do you mean console type :internal terminal?

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer I'd guess Thomas meant GDB.

Comment: When I open up Visual Studio, I can set the configuration to `Debug Mode`.  I can then set *breakpoints* and run the code.  I can use `F10` key to single step a statement and `F11` to step into functions.  Variables can be `add to Watch` to be displayed in a watch window.  This is what I mean.

Comment: There are other debuggers out there.  GDB will work if you built your code with the GNU Utilities.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you think immunity debugger will work (that's the one I have right now) I only ever used it when I was interested in buffer/stack overflows.. SO I don't see how this will help me.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I only use VS for c# and vb.net this project is in netbeans